# I have four parts - What am I?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

I have four parts,

One is only a small part,

One hides in the horses mouth,

One turns to open the door,

One in a hole of its own making,

The four together make me,

Alone I eat carefully,

Two of me bite.

What am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm gonna guess:

> nibble/nybble

Four parts:

> A nybble has four bits.

One is only a small part:

> A bit is a small part

One hides in the horses mouth:

> A bit (connected to/part of the reins) goes in a horses mouth

One turns to open the door:

> Looks like a door router bit is part of the hinge system. On further exploration the bit of a key is the part that actually engages the locking mechanism of a lock.

One in a hole of its own making:

> If you bit something you would make a hole (tenuous). On further inspection a drill bit is what makes the hole.

Alone I eat carefully:

> To nibble is to eat carefully.

Two of me bite:

> Two nybbles make a byte.

Comment: Quick.  Want to take a guess at the rest?

Comment: Yep, filling it in now!

Comment: +1 marked as correct but there are still two explanation that can be improved. ('One turns to open the door' and 'One in a hole of its own making')

Comment: @BrentHackers, thought it was those two! Have had another go :)

Comment: Yep.  Spot on now. +1